# Is Radha elder than Krishna interms of age during their marriage?

Tags: krishna, marriage, radha

[Brahmavaivarta Purana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahma_Vaivarta_Purana) says that Radha was [aunt](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31808/661) of Krishna and Radha was fourteen years elder than Krishna.

So, is it true that Radha is elder than Krishna **during** their marriage?

Answer (score 3):

### No

**Radha** *may* **not be elder than Krishna during the marriage between them**. It is not true that Radha is fourteen years elder than Krishna *during* their marriage time.

The reason is that Krishna takes the form of teenage youth before wedding moments

> Then the Supreme Personality of Godhead **became a teen-age youth**
> splendid as a dark cloud, dressed in yellow garments, decorated with
> the Kaustubha gem, holding a flute, and more enchanting than a great
> host of Kamadevas.
>
> [[18, Chapter 16: Description of Shri Radhika's Wedding, Canto 1, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.16:_Description_of_Shri_Radhika%27s_Wedding)

Krishna married Radha after taking the form of teenage youth only

> **Brahma performed the wedding-ceremony of Lord Hari and Shri Radhika.**
> He had Them circumambulate the sacred fire and bow down before it, and
> then Brahma, the knower of the Vedas, recited the seven mantras.
>
> [[32, Chapter 16: Description of Shri Radhika's Wedding, Canto 1, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.16:_Description_of_Shri_Radhika%27s_Wedding)

After the marriage, Krishna takes his original infant form

> As Radha was about to decorate Him, **Lord Krishna suddenly abandoned
> His teen-age form and again became an infant**. He became an infant
> crawling on the ground and crying, just as Nanda had given Him before.
>
> [[51-52, Chapter 16: Description of Shri Radhika's Wedding, Canto 1, Garga Samhita]](http://wikikrishna.com/index.php?title=GS_1.16:_Description_of_Shri_Radhika%27s_Wedding)

Thus, according to the scripture Garga Samhita, lord Krishna changes his form from infant to a teenage youth before marriage and married Radha in his teenage youth form and then again took his original infant form after marrying Radha.

Hence it is **false** that Radha is fourteen years elder than Krishna **during** their marriage time.

Comment: Even as per Garg Samhita, Radha was elder than Krishna.. What's the main purpose of this Q/A? Would original age be changed if someone changes the form for time being?.. let's say many actors do double role of different ages, so can one marry a girl of higher age after such make-up (changing form)..bdw if you are searching for instances where bride's age was more, we have another Q already..

Comment: @YDS The purpose of Q/A is to show that the marriage doesn't happened between the infant Krishna and teen-age radha. It was between teen-age Krishna and teen-age Radha.  Even the age is different before and after marriage, the age criteria was satisfied or preserved during marriage.

Comment: @YDS *we have another Q already* . Please tell me which Q you are referring to?

Comment: does this criteria satisfied if a boy takes form of higher age man and marry a girl of higher age..? bdw [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35191/12304) is the Q i m referring to..

Comment: @YDS I am not sure about exact age during marriage. Because it was not given exactly. That is the reason for using the word *may* in my answer.