# Age of boy and girl for marrige in Hinduism

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, marriage

I searched a lot, but couldn't find it. I want to know if a Hindu boy marries to **20 days elder girl**, would the marriage be **valid (शास्त्र सम्मत)** according to Hinduism?
Can anyone give me examples from Hindu scriptures of situations where the groom is younger than the bride? Please answer.

Comment: See this question -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10018/4732

Comment: For boys see this answer --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/47842/4732

Comment: Are there examples in scriptures of the situation said in my question?

Comment: Such examples are unlikely to be found in scriptures as it is against the rules but let others check too

Comment: the girl must be younger. if the girl is older, then the man's lifespan reduces each time he has sex with er.

Comment: Respected sir/mam, can you give any references for that? @mar

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35191/12304